# onMessageReceived not called when phone is asleep

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-wake-lock

I have created an app that starts an alarm when a message from FCM was received. The app works fine when it is in the foreground, in the background or when the activity is closed.

But when the phone has been in sleep mode for a long time (don't know the exact time) the onMessageReceived method isn't called until the phone is woken up manually. The FCM messages are data messages with high priority, which according to the documentation should be able to wake up the phone.

What are ways to fix this problem? 
Is using WakeLock the way to go, or is it to heavy on the battery life ?

Comment: I guess they has to be topic messages?? Right?

Comment: Yes, im sending the messages to a topic to which all app users are automatically subscribed to.

Comment: That is it @PaulB  you will always have some strange behaviours because topic messages although can have priority `high` they always tend to being given their own priority and look lower priority (sometimes) because they are considered very broad and not urgent. If your case wants a fastest way then send to devices or groups of devices. This is not documented just my experience!

Comment: Okay thank you for the input. I will try to send it directly to the device and see what happens.

Comment: I am sure that will always work if you set priority high. All the best **Happy Coding!**.

Answer (score 0):

Send notifications with this format from back end :

```
{ 


"notification" : {
    "click_action" : ".MainActivity", 
    "body" : "new Symulti update !", 
    "title" : "new Symulti update !", 
    "icon" : "ic_notif_symulti" }, 



"data": { ... },


"to" : "c9Vaa3ReGdk:APA91bH-AuXgg3lDN2WMcBrNhJZoFtYF9" }
```

The key here is add

```
"click_action" : ".MainActivity"
```

for handle click action.

Comment: Wouldn't this just have any effects when I click the notification in first place?